# Eager loading a lazy child collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have data model similar to this

```
class Office
{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "cafeteria_id")
   Cafeteria cafeteria;
}

class Cafeteria
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="cafeteria")
   @LazyCollection(value=LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
   List<Chair> chairs;
}

class Chair
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cafeteria_id")
    Cafeteria cafeteria;
}
```

I have a JPQL query like this

```
select o from Office o where o.cafeteria.someThing = ?
```

Above query works fine but in one case I would like a query which could eagerly load all the chairs(o.cafeteria.chairs) as well. How should I modify query to eagerly fetch all chairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fetch` attribute in `OneToMany` annotation. You can map the same relationship as many times as you want:

```
class Cafeteria {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="cafeteria")
   @LazyCollection(value=LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
   List<Chair> chairs;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="cafeteria")
   List<Chair> eagerlyLoadedChairs;
}
```

And then you can use any of them:

```
// Lazy loading
select o from Office o inner join o.cafeteria c inner join c.chairs ch where c.someThing = ?

// Eager loading
select o from Office o inner join o.cafeteria c inner join c.eagerlyLoadedChairsch where c.someThing = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either you change the fetch type from `Lazy` to `Eager`, but this will always load your List of `Chair` every time you load an object from Cafeteria.

like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="cafeteria", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@LazyCollection(value=LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
List<Chair> chairs;
```

OR In your `Service` that call this query, after calling it, you simply load the Chair list in your specific use case, check more about [Initializing Collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization) in Hibernate

```
Hibernate.initialize(cafeteria.getChairs());
```